# strpos always return false

Tags: php, strpos

It seems like I'm having an issue with `strpos()`
For some reason, it's always returning `false` when it should not.

This is where the issue occur :

```
if ( strpos( $attachment_url, $upload_dir_paths['baseurl'] ) !== false ) {
    //some code here
}
```

I've made a `var_dump` of `$attachment_url` and `$upload_dir_paths['baseurl']` and compared both values to make sure that the "needle" was in the "haystack" and in fact it was.

```
var_dump($upload_dir_paths['baseurl']);    //needle
var_dump($attachment_url);                 //haystack
```

Results of the `var_dump` above :

```
string(39) "//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads"
string(67) "//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/stunning-photograph.jpg"
```

Does anyone knows why the `if` statement is always returning `false`?

Thanks

Comment: `if ( strpos( "//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/stunning-photograph.jpg", "//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads") !== false ) {
    echo 'yes';
}` gives yes

Comment: Works for me: [https://3v4l.org/UC6pN](https://3v4l.org/UC6pN)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from the variable $upload_dir_paths['baseurl'].
The string "//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads" is composed of 35 characters unlike the 39 of your question.
I think that there are some "hidden" characters that cannot be rendered by your browser/your terminal.

How to solve the problem?
Maybe try the function "[trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)" on the variable $upload_dir_paths['baseurl']. It should solve the problem.

Comment: Even after trimming the string `$upload_dir_paths['baseurl']` I still get 39 characters which doesn't make any sense?

Comment: @Myguel That's strange... Maybe try a `substr($upload_dir_paths['baseurl'], 5)` and uif it's the same output but without the 39 chars, it means that the hidden characters have been removed.
If the characters of the string have been removed, then try the same method but like this: `substr($upload_dir_paths['baseurl'], 0, 35)`.    
If only a few characters have been removed, that means the hidden chars are in the string which seems more difficult for me to remove.